# jQuery Deleting dynamic row by buttonclick

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a table which each row has some info and a delete button as cells, and when the delete button is clicked the row which the button is in it should hide() how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

surely u used iterator for display rows. now add some class for that del button/cell and in jQuery write.

```
jQuery(".<class name>").click(function (){
    jQuery(this).parent("tr").hide();
});
```

hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If your html looks like this:

```
<tr><td>Some info</td><td><button>Delete</button></td></tr>
```

Then you can just bind this to the click event of the button

```
$(this).parents("tr").hide();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
      <tr>
        <td>Info Here</td><td>Another Info Here</td><td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" class="delete_button"></td>
      </tr>
```

and then in the js file:

```
$(".delete_button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().hide()
});
```

Just make sure you have jquery.